# python strip method showing inconsistent results

Tags: python

Why these below code behaves differently ?

Code 1:

```
line = '       dd--  -- '
len1 = len(line)
line2 = line.strip('')
len2 = len(line2)
print(line)
print(line2)
print(len1)
print(len2)
```

output:

```
       dd--  --
       dd--  --
16
16
```

Code 2:

```
line = '       dd--  -- '
len1 = len(line)
line2 = line.strip(' ')
len2 = len(line2)
print(line)
print(line2)
print(len1)
print(len2)
```

output:

```
       dd--  --
dd--  --
16
8
```

Comment: `''` and `' '` are two different arguments, and `line.strip` behaves different in each case. What do you think is inconsistent?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was assuming '' as leaving it as default. thank you

Comment: The default argument is `None`, not `''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strip` function takes a set of characters to remove as leading/trailing characters. In the first case, you are passing in an empty string, so nothing gets removed. In the second case, you are passing in a space character, which removes the 8 leading/trailing spaces. Since space is the default character to remove, it would be equivalent to writing `line.strip()`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was assuming '' as leaving it as default. thank you